# Time.now from server instead of client computers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I am not mistaken, the `Time.now` function in Ruby is taken from the client's computer. How can we ensure that it's taken from the server, so that it remains the same time as the server even if the client's date/month/year is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: No, Ruby is a server-side language, thus it's taken from the server.

Comment: @Karpie Ruby is not a server-side language. There is no such thing. Ruby executes code and uses the resources of the machine it's running on.

Comment: @Wouter de Bie: Which in the case of a web application is the web server, no?

Comment: @Wouter de Bie: anyways ruby code is executed in the server and has no connection to the client's computer

Comment: Ruby on Rails is a framework that handles client-server communication. Ruby itself is a language. The language has absolutely nothing to do with any networking. The statement "Ruby is a server-side language" is false. It would be the same as saying "English is a land language" or "German is a sea language". IMHO the correct answer to the question is that "Ruby uses the system clock to get the time from the machine it's running on".

Comment: @xinit, Ruby is a server-side language the same way PHP or ASP (*shivers*) is a "server-side language". Sure, to use your quirky analogy, Ruby is a land *and* sea language, but clients accessing your Ruby-powered websites will not be executing Ruby programs on their computer. This is all people are implying :)

Comment: ASP is not a language, but a scripting engine. You would use VBScript or C# or whatever ASP supports to program. ASP is a server-side component. PHP is a language that has a lot of functionality built in to build web applications. Ruby (the language) is neither server or client. It's just a language. Rails is a server side framework. Depending on where that language is executed, the Time is taken. In the case of Rails (the framework), I can imagine that you might think that the client time can be taken, but Ruby (the language) has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Time.now` is executed on the server.

If you'd like to set the timezone, add the following in `config/application.rb`

```
config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

To see all the timezones available, run the following command in your terminal

```
rake time:zones:all
```

In older versions of rails (`rails <= 3.x`), you can use

```
rake -D time
```

Answer (score 2):

Time.now is always evaluated on the server running the code. In the case of a Ruby on Rails application, this would be the web server.

Answer (score 1):

[`Time.now`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Time#now-class_method) only reports the time of the machine running the script. On its own the interpreter can't run code on a user's machine.